Which and how many purification systems exist in the New Testament
Mark 1:42  NVI

Immediately the leprosy left him and he was cleansed.

Which and how many purification systems exist in the New Testament (Christian Bible)?

The leper was cleansed when Jesus Christ put forth his hand and touched the man. This is not a 'system'. This is a Person. I am not clear as to what you are requiring.

There are numerous texts and modes of purification, especially involving the term ἐκαθαρίσθη. This isn't as simple as a mere “touch”—there's a wealth of context behind it.

May I suggest that you include your own research within the question, for the sake of clarity. Or, perhaps you are intending a comprehensive answer, yourself, from that same research.

I am at a complete loss as to wh at you are asking.

In the NT, "Truth" is not a set of facts but the person of Jesus Christ (John 14:6).  Similarly, purification was not a system but being acquainted with the person of Jesus Christ.  Jesus needed only to touch someone to heal or purify.

Baptism in water was one type of purification, the blood of Jesus another, there must be more...

@Betho's The water was the purification method before Jesus. The water was changed to wine at Cana, showing the method of purification was about to change. The wine (blood) is the new covenant. In Acts 2, Peter taught to be baptized with water for the remission of sins. But later in chapter 10, Gentiles receive the Holy Spirit without water baptism. They learned that the water was no longer the purifying element. Blood is the new covenant. Water and Blood represent the 2 covenants. Through both, the church was born from Jesus pierced side.
